# How to display third party widget in angular2 component

Tags: angular

i am trying to use this widget in my angular2 application but it's not rendering in view.

https://oil-price.net/dashboard.php

Adding this script tag in component but it's not rending..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.oil-price.net/TABLE3/gen.php?lang=en">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your index.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.oil-price.net/TABLE2/gen.php?lang=en"> </script>
<noscript> To get the WTI <a href="http://www.oil-price.net/dashboard.php?lang=en#TABLE2">oil price</a>, please enable Javascript.</noscript>
```

Will work fine.

Comment: I have added this but in angular2 Since Angular removes script tags from the template (not sure if this is just CLI behavior or Angular itself), I can't set the initial script tag. Nor can I figure out how I would update please let me know if you can help.

Comment: yes, just put the required script below the body tag of index,html